# https not working with Slim

Tags: https, slim, middleware

I have recently setup my EC2 LAMP server with SSL which works fine with Slim. I can securely log in to phpMyAdmin and see my data just fine too. However I get 504 gateway time out error on my routes that connect to mysql. My routes work fine when the same index.php file is on my local XAMPP server (which is not SSL enabled). So it appears to me that the https protocol is not yet working on LAMP server. Looking around I have seen things about modifying my .htaccess file to rewrite for https:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]`
```

but this has not made any difference and I have no idea why. Middleware has also come up too, to redirect http to https and this seems like a good option, but I have no idea where to begin with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simplify the `.htaccess` file a little bit and move the SSL check and redirect to a middleware.

### Content of `.htaccess`

```
# Redirect to front controller
RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

### Middleware

```
// Redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS
$app->add(function (Request $request, Response $response, $next) {
    $uri = $request->getUri();
    if($uri->getScheme() !== 'https') {
        // Map http to https
        $httpsUrl = $uri->withScheme('https')->withPort(443)->__toString();

        // Redirect to HTTPS Url
        return $response->withRedirect($httpsUrl);
    }

    return $next($request, $response);
});
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your response, I replaced my .htaccess contents with your suggestion and added the middleware code to my index.php file, but still not working, but i do get a new error: This page is not working... http error 500

Comment: 500 is an very general error. To see what's going on set the `displayErrorDetails` setting to true. [Details](https://gist.github.com/odan/d2b889c350aa2ea0ff8e5ca93ce588a2#errors-and-logging)

Comment: Ok will do that tomorrow. Thanks for that.

Comment: Hi again, where is the file located containing    
   $config['displayErrorDetails'] = true; ??? thanks

Comment: It depends. Try: `src/settings.php` or `config/settings.php`. [Example](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Skeleton/blob/master/src/settings.php)

Comment: Ok I don't have a settings.php so I created in my project folder and added your example to it. The slim site [here](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/tutorial/first-app.html) says to point to it so I did but still no log/mssg in my browser. I also cleared cache.

Comment: The Slim tutorial is not optimized for the LAMP stack. Could you please try this [tutorial](https://gist.github.com/odan/d2b889c350aa2ea0ff8e5ca93ce588a2) instead?

Comment: Hello Hi, thanks for this tutorial, this seems vastly better than what i had before, but I'm having trouble pretty early in the 'starting' section. I've created the directories and files as shown and copied the file contents. My document root is set to my project's public folder. When I enter http://host/project/ or http://host/project/hello/world i get '404 Not Found'. Both .htaccess files are in their right places. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: The name `project` is just an example name and could be anything. The correct url should be then: http://hostname/hello/world

Comment: Ok I found the error: The tutorial's config/middleware.php file contained an opening php tag with no code. I removed it and it now works. I will carry on.Thanks

Comment: Only route for the 'It works' default page message works but not the route for hello/world. <https://myhost> <- working   <https://myhost/hello/world> or <https://myhost/myprofect/hello/world> <- not working. And I noticed something very strange, just for testing if I removed one or both of the .htaccess files it makes no difference to the output, so they don't appear to be having any affect.

Comment: The Apache mod_rewrite module must be installed. Here is a [test script](https://gist.github.com/odan/64606e3668eac0e13afc).

Comment: I think the rewrite module is already enabled because I checked that a while ago, and I'm using Fedora and I think its just a case of changing 'AllowOverideNone' to 'AllowOverideAll' of /var/www directory in httpd.conf. Is this what you mean?

Comment: It should be `AllowOverride FileInfo`. [Details](https://gist.github.com/odan/dcf6c3155899677ee88a4f7db5aac284#enable-apache-mod_rewrite)

Comment: Thanks I tried that and restarted. No luck. I think that's for Ubuntu, I'm using Fedora.

Comment: Ok it's working. No one said anything about changing the document root path AND the directory path in httpd.conf. But your input has been helpful.

Comment: Amazing! Everything works and better than ever before. Had a few silly problems cos I am a noob to server side programming, but got through the tutorial and BAM! I can fetch all data over https even without having any code in middleware (which is a bit strange) but anyway it all works. Thank you very much sir, you've helped end my last few days of hell. All the best.